# Limitations of Excel using certain formula structure for averaging the first N decimal comma delimited text in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have discovered a situation/anomaly where, using certain formula structure, Excel is unable to find the average of the 1st 35 numbers in a comma delimited string in a cell. It can find the average of 34 or less decimal numbers, or 35 NON-decimal numbers. Also, G-Sheets is able to perform the calculation.

So, it has been established that 34 decimal numbers appears to be the threshold that Excel can calculate (with this specific formula), and i am seeking to find out what the limitation might be.

The string:

```
2262.2,2264.65,2253.45,2286.4,2289.6,2311.5,2385.45,2404.75,2403.9,2373.55,2440.5,2471.55,2492.75,2563.1,2571.95,2558.2,2554.15,2538.3,2518.35,2420.5,2420.5,2392,2374.3,2333.4,2287.85,2249.4,2236.3,2208.45,2212.05,2236.35,2263.6,2242.75,2304.4,2309.85,2259.7
```

Whole formula:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","#",$F$1))-1),A2),",",REPT(" ",LEN(IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","#",$F$1))-1),A2)))),
ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","#",$F$1))-1),A2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","#",$F$1))-1),A2),",",""))+1))*LEN(IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","#",$F$1))-1),A2)),LEN(IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","#",$F$1))-1),A2)))),IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","#",$F$1))-1),A2))
```

The above formula is made up of the following components..

Average of a comma delimited string:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&A2,",",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),
ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1))*LEN(A2),LEN(A2))),A2)
```

Extracting the N 1st comma delimited numbers:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","#",$F$1))-1),A2)
```

I am not specifically looking for a solution, but rather knowledge/explanation what the limitation is that prevents Excel from handling 35 (or more) decimal numbers when using the complete aforementioned formula.

It should be noted that the following FILTERXML formula (which is much shorter than the one above) is reported to work for 35 decimal numbers, but as i am on Mac i am unable to test it myself:

```
=AVERAGE(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[position()<="&F$1&"]"))
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: As i work on Mac and in G-Sheets, it is relevant for my needs.

Comment: It works in G-Sheets, so i am not looking for a formula for that. Please read the post where i have stated i am asking for explanation of the Excel limitation. Once i understand the limitation then i can try to work with it, or find a solution. This enquiry is not specifically asking for a solution but is asking for explanation of the limitation so that i know what i am working with.

Comment: The limit for your formula is the length of the string: it works for more numbers as long as the total length of the string is <=255 characters.

Not sure which subexpression is causing the problem.

Comment: @Scott, thank you. i will learn how your formula works, and see how it could still complete the average when the string has less than N.

Comment: @ShaneShepherd it is the FIND that has a 255 character limit.  My version works because it does not use FIND.

Comment: @ScottCraner I believe the issue is the length of the result of the `SUBSTITUTE` portion of the formula.  `SUBSTITUTE(2,",",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))`  When the length of that result becomes >32,767 (maximum number characters in a formula), the formula will return `#VALUE!`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld you are correct as soon as I made the string provided by the OP long enough it errored.

Comment: investigating from all comments so far: the formula from @ScottCraner does not use ```INDIRECT```, and in the "average" components of my formula which does use ```INDIRECT``` falls over at the last 3 characters. Im not sure if that is relevant.

Comment: This subexpression works and returns an array of 35 strings. the longest string is 225 characters

    =MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&A2,",",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1))*LEN(A2),LEN(A2))

but this returns an array of 35 #Value - don't know why it fails

    =--MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&A2,",",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1))*LEN(A2),LEN(A2))

Comment: The fundamental problem is that you're using a horribly convoluted formula. Even if it worked, it would be awful to maintain and modify. Good luck to anyone who inherits the spreadsheet. It would be better to direct effort into finding a better approach, like (in Google Sheets) =AVERAGE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(A2,","), 1, F1))

Comment: or =AVERAGE(--textsplit(A2,",")) where textsplit is a LAMBDA function (written by Microsoft Research)

Comment: @CharlesWilliams I believe the behavior of your 2nd formula can be mimicked by comparing `--REPT(1,256)` => `#VALUE!` and `--REPT(1,255)` => 1.11E+254.  When I apply your formula to the OP's string, I get multiple strings of 258 characters. If I remove one number from the string, the lengths are 251 characters and no errors appear.  You can `TRIM` your second formula to:  `=--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&A2,",",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1))*LEN(A2),LEN(A2)))` and then there will be no error.

Comment: I think LAMBDA textsplit won't work on Apple, since it uses FILTERXML in the background, which only works for Windows computers.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld  Yes its a 255 character limit for text to number coercion _ I got fooled because the last string in the array looked the longest but actually had no trailing blanks so was only 225 characters, but the others are 258, But using TRIM bypasses the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are running into various Excel limitations.

In your specific formula, you are running into a limitation of the double unary (also seems to apply to the `VALUE` and `NUMBERVALUE` functions) where the text string cannot be longer than 255 characters (I've not seen this documented, but easily confirmed empirically).

That can be corrected by adding a `TRIM` function to the portion of the formula that creates the array of numbers. eg:

```
=--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&A2,",",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1))*LEN(A2),LEN(A2)))
```

Depending on the actual length of your string, you may run into the formula length limitation of `32,767` characters when a string that long is the result of the `SUBSTITUTE` function.

Depending on the length of the individual numbers, you will hit that limit with 60-70 numbers in the string.